# OpenCV: RANSAC confidence parameter for finding a homography

Tags: image-processing, opencv, homography

The OpenCV function `findhomography()` finds a homographic transformation between matching points of two images. (See [Definition](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography))

For finding matching subsets of points RANSAC can be used.

Here's the catch: In contrast to other function in OpenCV which use RANSAC (e.g. `findfundamentalMat` (See [Definition](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat))) the RANSAC parameter for **confidence** **cannot** be changed. Only the reprojection threshold can be passed as an argument.

I looked in the OpenCV source, and for `findhomography()` the confidence is hardcoded to 0.995.

For my purposes I need to increase this. Is there a way to do this without changing the value in the OpenCV source itself?

Is there a reason why this should be hardcoded?

PS: I added a change [request under Ticket 1557](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1557) for the next subversion.

Comment: Both definition links are now dead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to be hardcoded is that for the majority of users, this is a very good choice.

Maybe you were the first to feel the need for something more. But this is why OpenCV is open - take the code, modify it, make a patch and propose it to OpenCV dev team - whatever you like.

And, are you sure this is what you need? Usually, a tighter reproj threshold will do the trick. If you have problems, they may be somewhere else - some badly chosen points, a too big fit error on point matching, etc.

Comment: You are right: I could just change it myself and participate in the development. In fact, this is what I did in my local subversion and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you are not the first that needs to change harcoded variables or functions in OpenCV. Actually we are changing a lot of OpenCV functions in order to make them faster and more efficient for mobile phones.
If you want to change RANSAC, just create a copy of the class with a different name

```
class  CvModelEstimator2
{

}
```

in your code, and modify it yourself as you need. You can also change the maxnumber of iterations for RANSAC, the default is very high and makes application really slow.